# How to Get Status of Only a Directory in Subversion

Tags: svn, directory, diff, status

Is there a Subversion command that only provides a status (Added, Modified, Deleted, etc.) of a specified directory on the remote repository? Currently, if `diff` is passed on, status of all the files and sub-folders is displayed, e.g.:

```
svn diff -summarize -rXXX:HEAD http://repo/url/trunk/new/path

A    http://repo/url/trunk/new/path/file1.txt
A    http://repo/url/trunk/new/path/file2.txt
A    http://repo/url/trunk/new/path/file3.txt
A    http://repo/url/trunk/new/path/file4.txt
A    http://repo/url/trunk/new/path
```

The output I would like to get is only the information for `path/` directory and no child files/directory, e.g.:

```
A    http://repo/url/trunk/new/path
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `depth` [option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.depth) for `svn status`

Comment: Actually, `--depth empty` works with `svn diff` too.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it specified which depth option achieves the outcome desired as asked in the original question. I'd document it and edit but I cannot get any depth option to work in a local svn checkout (to only show me the folders/directories modified)